# Taylor expansion of a vector norm

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to derive equations where the Taylor expansion about an equilibrium state is involved as following.

$\lvert\lvert \mathbf{x}_{0} + \epsilon \mathbf{x}_{1} \rvert\rvert = \lvert\lvert \mathbf{x}_{0} \rvert\rvert + \epsilon \frac{\mathbf{x}_{1}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{0}}{\lvert\lvert\mathbf{x}_{0}\rvert\rvert}+O\left(\epsilon^2\right)$,

where $\mathbf{x}_{0}$ is an equilibrium solution and $\mathbf{x}_{1}$ is a small perturbation. Is the above expansion correct? Or, is there anything I did wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: was there a differential equation you were solving ?

Comment: Thanks cactus314, I was in the middle of linearization of variables about its steady solution $\mathbf{x}_o$.